# Bicycle chain roller diameter size chart?

Tags: chain, gears, sprocket, design, rollers

I'm digging for a while now, and can not find any helpful chart for chain roller diameters e.g. Shimano 8,9,10,11,12 speed. It differs of course depending on the manufacturer and the purpose. We know that ANSI standard 40R chain roller is 0.312" (7.9mm). We know some measurements like this one e.g. https://handsonbike.blogspot.com/2022/01/shimano-11-speed-vs-sram-axs-12-speed.html but we don't know how accurate are they.

Does manufacturer share such size chart? Is there any? Somewhere? I don't believe designers measure every possible chain by hand every time.

Comment: Hey man, so I'm designing a chain ring for manufacturing and here I am looking up data online to cross reference what I've found by measuring every possible chain by hand. (every chain that I currently have access to)

Comment: For what it's worth: Campagnolo 12s measured 7.7mm, Campagnolo 10s 7.65mm, Shimano 11s 7.6mm, SRAM 8s 7.6mm.